# Display a simple structure in a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to display this structure in a treeview: A Product has a TreeViewItem and each TreeViewItem may have a list of TreeViewItems themself:

```
class Product {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public TreeViewItem Item {get; set;}
}

class TreeViewItem {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<TreeViewItem> Subitems {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried this, which I thought would work:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Product.Item}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataModel:TreeViewItem}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

    </TreeView>
```

But it displays nothing. I have tried for quite some time now, but feel lost and would be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you assign to `TreeView.ItemsSource` must implement `IEnumerable` and you need to also specify an ItemsSource on the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

```
class Product {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public TreeViewItem Item {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> Items { get { return new[] { item }; }
}

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Product.Items}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataModel:TreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Glen! How could I add the product name as topmost node?

Comment: Make Product a TreeViewItem, put it in an IEnumerable and use it as the ItemsSource

Comment: Product is not a TreeViewItem, it contains some more properties :o(

Comment: Add another HierarchicalDataTemplate, same as before, but set the DataType to Product and the ItemsSource to Items. Then you will need to put your product into an IEnumerable and use that as the TreeView.ItemsSource